# restSQL war deployment issue

Tags: java, sql, rest, tomcat

I'm trying to deploy restSQL in my local tomcat installation based on this [link.](http://restsql.org/doc/Deployment.html)

From my tomcat webapps folder:

> webapps\restsql-0.8\WEB-INF\classes\resources\properties

I have modified `'default-restsql.properties'` to set the correct database connections

and retained the property `'sqlresources.dir=/resources/xml/sqlresources'` while adding/creating the folder on that location.

I also modified in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.restsql.properties</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/resources/properties/default-restsql.properties</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I'm quite sure that the `default.restsql.properties` is loaded since when I access this resource:

```
http://localhost:8080/restsql-0.8/conf
```

I get this response:

```
Properties loaded from /resources/properties/default-restsql.properties:
log4j.configuration = resources/properties/default-log4j.properties
org.restsql.security.Authorizer = org.restsql.security.impl.AuthorizerImpl
org.restsql.core.RequestLogger = org.restsql.core.impl.RequestLoggerImpl
**sqlresources.dir = /resources/xml/sqlresources**
database.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
logging.config = resources/properties/default-log4j.properties
database.user = root
org.restsql.core.Factory.ResponseSerializerFactory = org.restsql.core.impl.ResponseSerializerFactoryImpl
org.restsql.core.SqlBuilder = org.restsql.core.impl.SqlBuilderImpl
database.password = root
org.restsql.core.Factory.ConnectionFactory = org.restsql.core.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl
org.restsql.core.SqlResourceMetaData = org.restsql.core.impl.SqlResourceMetaDataMySql
org.restsql.core.HttpRequestAttributes = org.restsql.core.impl.HttpRequestAttributesImpl
logging.facility = log4j
response.useXmlSchema = false
org.restsql.core.Factory.RequestFactory = org.restsql.core.impl.RequestFactoryImpl
database.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/
logging.dir = /var/log/restsql
org.restsql.core.Factory.SqlResourceFactory = org.restsql.core.impl.SqlResourceFactoryImpl
request.useXmlSchema = false
response.useXmlDirective = false
org.restsql.core.Factory.RequestDeserializerFactory = org.restsql.core.impl.RequestDeserializerFactoryImpl

Properties using defaults:
org.restsql.core.Factory.Connection = org.restsql.core.impl.ConnectionFactoryImpl
java.util.logging.config.file = resources/properties/default-logging.properties
request.useXmlDirective = false
org.restsql.properties = /resources/properties/default-restsql.properties
```

However when I access this resources

```
http://localhost:8080/restsql-0.8/res/
```

I get this response:

> SQL Resources directory /resources/xml/sqlresources does not exist ... please
>   correct your sqlresources.dir property in your restsql.properties file

Although the folder do exist: `webapps\restsql-0.8\WEB-INF\classes\resources\xml\sqlresources`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Does `/resources/xml/sqlresources` refer to an absolute path in your filesystem? Try to create this directory to test it ...

Comment: I tried changing the property to: sqlresources.dir=%TOMCAT_HOME%/webapps/restsql-0.8/WEB-INF/classes/resources/xml/sqlresources still getting the same problem. When I do a 'cd' via the command prompt with that directory I get to the right folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry you're having trouble with deployment. restSQL requires an absolute path to the main properties file. It does not have the capability to search its WAR file or exploded web app dir, other than look in the classpath for the default.

Most paths are to other files, referenced in the main restSQL properties files have to be absolute. The only one that is relative is the logging.config. Please have a look at  [Deployment](http://restsql.org/doc/Deployment.html) for all the nitty-gritty deployment instructions.

Hope that does the trick for you.

Comment: It did however I'm getting another issue when I access a 'resource': Definition requires table element for , referenced by column country_id    I suspect the reason for this is because the table is empty, since I am not able to run sakila-data.sql from within pqAdmin. In your case, how did you populated the sakila tables? I tried 'psql' but executing "/i C:/postgresql/sakila-data.sql" does not do anything, the tables are still empty...

Answer (score 0):

When it rains it pours?

Sounds like you had trouble running one of the database create scripts? Is that in restsql-sdk/WebContent/database/postgresql? Did you have errors running create-sakila.bat? Perhaps your psql executable is not in your path. You can edit the file to add it to your PATH environment variable temporarily.

You won't get any 5xx errors if the resource query returns no data. You will get a 200 with an empty readResponse document.

Your problem is likely a resource definition metadata issue. Is country_id from the country table? Is country defined as a table in the metadata? Can you post the resource definition?

Have you looked over the SQL resource rules at http://restsql.org/doc/SqlResourceRules.html? Sorry, SQL Functions and views are not allowed. You must use plain old columns and tables.